# Can I control the transition (ie through user swiping) between two view controllers?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, custom-transition

I wish to have one view controller slide off the screen as the user drags it, with the user able to drag their fingers back and forth to control the transition.

I know that custom transitions are possible, and was wondering if this was possible?

Comment: This is absolutely possible, take a look at this [link](https://github.com/zoonooz/ZFDragableModalTransition). It's a component that already implements what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use a gesture recognizer that initiates custom transition and and also updates interaction controller (e.g. a `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`). The specifics depend upon whether the transition is modal or navigation controller.

- For `presentViewController`, your destination view controller needs to specify a custom transition type and specify a `transitioningDelegate`. This `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` can specify both the animation controller and the interaction controller.
- For navigation controllers, you would specify the `delegate` of the navigation controller, and there are `UINavigationControllerDelegate` methods you can implement to specify the animation and interaction controllers.

See WWDC 2013 video [Custom Transitions Using View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=218) which discusses this in great detail.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

One possible solution might be `UIPageViewController`

Comment: If the OP is looking for something more custom than this, I've also found this blog post to be very helpful: http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/